# C++11 Memory ordering acquire release issue

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-model

Based on standard there is the following example

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
 
std::atomic<bool> x = {false};
std::atomic<bool> y = {false};
std::atomic<int> z = {0};
 

    void write_x()
    {
        x.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    }
     
    void write_y()
    {
        y.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    }
     
    void read_x_then_y()
    {
        while (!x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
            ;
        if (y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
            ++z;
    }
     
    void read_y_then_x()
    {
        while (!y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
            ;
        if (x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
            ++z;
    }
     
    int main()
    {
        std::thread a(write_x);
        std::thread b(write_y);
        std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
        std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
        a.join(); b.join(); c.join(); d.join();
        assert(z.load() != 0); // will never happen
    }
```

Based on standard load of x/y happens after x/y are stored. Due to this no assert is fired
If the code above is changed as following

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
 
std::atomic<bool> x = {false};
std::atomic<bool> y = {false};
std::atomic<int> z = {0};
 
void write_x()
{
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}
 
void write_y()
{
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}
 
void read_x_then_y()
{
    while (!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ;
    if (y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ++z;
}
 
void read_y_then_x()
{
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ;
    if (x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ++z;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread a(write_x);
    std::thread b(write_y);
    std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
    std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
    a.join(); b.join(); c.join(); d.join();
    assert(z.load() != 0); // will never happen
}
```

Then the assert is fired.
**But my question is when the stored value x/y is known to the other threads?**
Based on the standard there is the following statement

All memory writes (including non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B. That is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory. This promise only holds if B actually returns the value that A stored, or a value from later in the release sequence.

Thread writes value x. Is the new value x known to thread B when thread c or d loads the variable x?
What is exactly the race condition that fires the assert?

Comment: In this program, there are two writes, and neither happens-before the other; they are unordered. The paragraph you cite, talking about "memory writes ...  that happened-before the atomic store", doesn't apply to the situation at hand. It's also unclear what you mean by "known to thread B when thread C does something": what is known or not known to thread B can only be detected when thread B does something.

Comment: "_when_": The important bit is that there doesn't need to be a global total order in which stores become visible across threads, so you can't assign points in time. The order can be different from the point of view of different threads. (Sequential consistency provides for such a global order though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on standard load of x/y happens after x/y are stored. Due to this no assert is fired

More precisely, the single total modification order of sequentially consistent operations means that the operations of store x, store y, and the loads happen in *some* order.

In particular, either the store of x or store of y happens first in this modification order. Let's say it's x. Then, in the thread that waits for y to be true, afterward it must load true for x.

> What is exactly the race condition that fires the assert?

There is no ordering. read_x_then_y may load x true and then y false, and read_y_then_x may load y true and then x false.

Comment: Will  reordering  will happen   command in read_x_then_y , ead_y_then_x .   x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) to be executed before while (!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        ; What does it mean that there is no ordering? write_x for example is not quarantee to be visible when  load on x takes palce on read_x_then_y @Jeff Garrett

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by no ordering. The store to x is not guaranteed to happen before the load of x, i.e. to be visible to the load of x.